# Lint error: WrongViewCast with findViewById passed as parameter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lint

Since I updated to Android Studio 3.0 refuses to build release APK and throws lint `WrongViewCast` errors. In 2.x and previous versions there were none.

Problem is that in offending code result of `findViewById` is passed as parameter to constructor expecting `View` instance. Since all views descend from `View` class and `findViewById` itself returns `View` this is rather unexpected scenario.

Code that produces lint `WrongViewCast` error is rather basic:

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*ViewWrapper.java*

```
import android.view.View;

public class ViewWrapper
{
    private View contentView;

    public ViewWrapper(View content)
    {
        contentView = content;
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // this line shows WrongViewCast error
        ViewWrapper v = new ViewWrapper(findViewById(R.id.text)); 
    }    
}
```

Replacing above offending line of code with following does not throw error

```
    View tv = findViewById(R.id.text);
    ViewWrapper v = new ViewWrapper(tv);
```

Of course, suppressing lint errors with `@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")` annotation or in gradle using

```
lintOptions {
    disable 'WrongViewCast'
}
```

also works fine.

Question is why `ViewWrapper v = new ViewWrapper(findViewById(R.id.text));` shows error? Is that bug in lint or I am missing something obvious?